# Power Query - creating a tracker for multiple studies

Tags: group-by, powerquery

New to Power Query and trying to learn how I can use it more to optimize workflows.

Here, I have multiple tables (1 for each study), and am trying to create a tracker that can identify the subject, whether or not they are participating in a specific study, and other data (e.g., study ID). Each table has:

1. Unique subject identifier (which could be used to link them across studies)
2. Study-specific identifier
3. Other misc info (dates of test1, test2, etc)

I am trying to make something that groups the columns of all my tables by the unique subject identifier, and then could have columns for "Study1", "Study 2", "Study 3" with a simple Y/N to show whether or not they are participating in that study. If Y, then also show the study-specific identifier. However, I am stuck.

I've appended all 3 tables into 1 master table - which results in duplicates as a participant can be in multiple studies. When I try the "Group By" function, I group by "Unique subject identifier" with new columns Study1, Study2, Study3, etc and operation "All rows". When I expand these however, it creates multiple duplicate rows, which defeats the purpose of the "Group by" function.

Would appreciate any suggestions you may have.

**Example**

Each table has some variation of these columns:

| Unique participant identifier | Unique Study identifier | Date of Test 1, etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 01-Apr-2022 |
| B | 101 | 02-Apr-2022 |
| C | 102 | 03-Apr-2022 |

Let's say Participant A is on study 1 only. Participant B is on Study 2 (study ID 201) and 3 (study ID 301). Participant C is on all 3 (study IDs 102, 202, and 302 respectively).

I am trying to make a table that will show:

| Unique participant identifier | Study 1 | Study 1 Identifier | Study 2 | Study 2 Identifier | Study 3 | Study 3 Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Y | 100 |  |  |  |  |
| B | Y | 101 | Y | 201 | Y | 301 |
| C | Y | 102 |  |  | Y | 302 |

Alongside the dates of tests (not shown, but same concept). These tables are updated as we go along, so power query would draw these data from the tables to create a "live" tracker.

The current code I have in the advanced editor is:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({STUDY1, STUDY2, STUDY3}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Unique participant identifier"}, {{"STUDY12", each _, type table}, {"STUDY22", each _, type table}, {"STUDY32", each _, type table}}),
    #"Expanded STUDY12" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "STUDY12", {"STUDY1-Study ID", "STUDY1-ABC Study ID", "STUDY1"}, {"STUDY12.STUDY1-Study ID", "STUDY12.STUDY1-ABC Study ID", "STUDY12.STUDY1"}),
    #"Expanded STUDY22" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded STUDY12", "STUDY22", {"STUDY2-Study ID", "STUDY2-OC Study ID", "STUDY2"}, {"STUDY22.STUDY2-Study ID", "STUDY22.STUDY2-ABC Study ID", "STUDY22.STUDY2"}),
    #"Expanded STUDY32" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded STUDY22", "STUDY32", {"STUDY3-Study ID", "STUDY3"}, {"STUDY32.STUDY3-Study ID", "STUDY32.STUDY3"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded STUDY32",{" Unique participant identifier ", "STUDY12.STUDY1-Study ID", "STUDY12.STUDY1", "STUDY12.STUDY1-ABC Study ID", "STUDY22.STUDY2", "STUDY22.STUDY2-Study ID", "STUDY22.STUDY2-ABC Study ID", "STUDY32.STUDY3", "STUDY32.STUDY3-Study ID"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

Done via the "Group by" function. This creates multiple rows for each participant though.

Comment: To add: let's say I have 3 studies - if a participant is on all 3, and I expand following "Group by", I end up with 9 rows, only 1 of which has all the correct info. But the row differs depending on how many studies they're participating in, so I'm not sure if this is "filterable"

Comment: Please post a sample of your input data, your desired output, and the code you are currently using, pasted from home ... advanced editor ... in your query. Otherwise we have no idea what you are doing or want to achieve

Comment: Suggest you edit your question after reading the help topic for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also include sample of your original data that can be copy/pasted as well as a screenshot of how you would like your results to appear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited post to include example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method. Your sample data is not that great. You also dont mention how to divide the Unique Study identifier into buckets. I assume it is just the integer portion of the number divided 100.  This is a bit long to attempt to make the steps obvious

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Unique participant identifier", type text}, {"Unique Study identifier", Int64.Type}, {"Date of Test", type date}}),
// there needs to be some way to identify groups of studies. I am using the hundreds place to find that
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "StudyNumber", each Number.RoundDown([Unique Study identifier]/100)),
// first table -- studies only
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date of Test"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US")[StudyNumber]), "StudyNumber", "Unique Study identifier", List.Sum),
// second tabe -- study dates only
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Unique Study identifier"}),
#"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns2", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns2", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US")[StudyNumber]), "StudyNumber", "Date of Test"),
RenamedColumns = Table.TransformColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column1", each if _="Unique participant identifier" then _ else _&" Date"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(RenamedColumns,{"Unique participant identifier"}),
// combine the tables
combined = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(#"Pivoted Column")&Table.ToColumns( #"Removed Columns1"),Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column") &Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns1"))
in combined
```

[image]

code version for yes/no

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Unique participant identifier", type text}, {"Unique Study identifier", Int64.Type}, {"Date of Test", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "StudyNumber", each Number.RoundDown([Unique Study identifier]/100)),
// first table -- studies only
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date of Test"}),
#"Rounded Off" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"StudyNumber", each Text.From(_) &" Identifier"}}),
Part1 = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rounded Off", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rounded Off", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US")[StudyNumber]), "StudyNumber", "Unique Study identifier", List.Sum),
// 2nd  table -- YN only
#"Change to Y" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Unique Study identifier",each "Y" }}),
#"Rounded Off1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Change to Y",{{"StudyNumber", each "Study " &Text.From(_)}}),
Pivot = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rounded Off1", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rounded Off1", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US")[StudyNumber]), "StudyNumber", "Unique Study identifier"),
Part2 = Table.RemoveColumns(Pivot,{"Unique participant identifier"}),
// 3rd table -- study dates only
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Unique Study identifier"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns2", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns2", {{"StudyNumber", type text}}, "en-US")[StudyNumber]), "StudyNumber", "Date of Test"),
RenamedColumns3 = Table.TransformColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column", each if _="Unique participant identifier" then _ else _&" Date"),
Part3 = Table.RemoveColumns(RenamedColumns3,{"Unique participant identifier"}),
// combine the tables
combined = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Part1)&Table.ToColumns( Part2)&Table.ToColumns( Part3),Table.ColumnNames(Part1) &Table.ColumnNames(Part2)&Table.ColumnNames(Part3))
in combined
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah the Y/N column is probably redundant and could be removed. 
The actual tables are slightly more complex but I can't post for confidentiality reasons. I am trying to understand what you did in your code as the output IS what I am looking for, but I am not sure I understand. 

Essentially - would I be combining into 1 first, essentially then change them into pivoted columns, and then combine them back together into a single table?
I am new to Power Query but am not understanding why you are adding, only to remove, certain columns.

Comment: you can only pivot on one column at a time.   So first I remove the date leaving Identifier and pivot.  Then I go back to original data, remove the identifier leaving date and pivot.   Then I just put the two sets of pivoted data next to each other by combining their tables.  Unless I want to have unique participant identifier repeated 2 times, I also have to remove that from the 2nd table before merging it in. There is also an extra step in there to rename the columns

Comment: paste my code into home...advanced editor... and step through the code with my sample data to see what is going on

Comment: Hey horseyride, thanks so much for your help! I haven't tried to tackle Y/N column yet, but was able to slowly apply the example you provided to my tables and it works great. Appreciate your help on this!!!